# bootstrap columns getting stacked even at larger screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First time using Bootstrap, took the template directly form here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_webpage&stacked=h

And did some changes:
Extra css added:

```
  .affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 52px;
  }

  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {

    [class*="col-"] {
      margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

  }

 .row.content {height: 1080px;}
```

And i added multiple things in the `<div col-sm-8>` i added many columns and columns inside columns such that they add up to 12 everytime but now what is happening is my top most columns i.e. the left sidebar and the content are stacked even at large screen. i.e first only the left side bar is visible then i scroll down to see the main content and the right side bar is not visible here at all.

Here is the entire code:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM4NCPJ27YEY

Comment: Hello, 
You've got your content outside of the row containing the sidebar and you have a closing tag `</div>` that should'nt be here. Find the closing tag of `<div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">` and remove it.

Comment: @Kangouroops thank you for looking at my code but i don't understand. i fail to see if i have any content outside of the row containing the sidebar andi rechecked and i am sure that all my tags are properly closed. Please point me out where i am wrong

Comment: `<div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="sidebar"> 
          <!-- <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> `  You close `<div class="row content">` and then open `<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">`, don't you want `<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">` inside it ?

Comment: @Kangouroops dude you just saved my ass big time! you debugged that yourself or there is something automated for things like that? also is there a way to solve my right sidebar not lfushing to the bottom on xs? ofcourse after removing that `</div>` tag

Comment: Just looking at the syntax highlighting you could see that you had one closing tag not corresponding to any opening tag. For your other problem, I must tell you that you have a huge lack of row and your divs don't have the height the should have, many things should get fixed

Comment: @Kangouroops please elaborate what you meain by huge lack of row and divs don't have the same height they should have. can you link me to some documentation where i can read some more about how to solve  my problem

Comment: Sure : Bootstrap website https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/ You have floating elements in floating elements in floating elements, and so on. You should clear your floating elements. That's what the class `row` is for in bootstrap. Before using bootstrap, it could be interesting to understand how floating elements work

Comment: Please, be sure to read this part : 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a syntax error,

There is an extra `div` closing tag which is located exactly before `<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">` which was acting like the closing tag of `<div class="row content">` and this is totally wrong because all `col` shall be inside the same `row` container, removing it will solve the issue.

Check the updated snippet.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM4NZ59ZLBEI

Comment: thanks for that but a new problem is that after applying your solution my right sidebar on xs screen is overlapping some parts of my main content. can you solve that?